# Running pacman in arch bang

Tags: linux, arch-linux

I have installed arch bang in my vmware workstation. The internet works fine but the pacman is not working 
Output of `pacman -Syy` :

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed to update core (no servers configured for repository)
error: failed to update extra (no servers configured for repository)
error: failed to update community (no servers configured for repository)
error: failed to synchronize any databases
error: failed to init transaction (no servers configured for repository)
```

I am running behind a proxy with bridged network adapter. How do I make the pacman work?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment and ask you if you've uncommented any repositories in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`, but that looks to me like what's happening. Have you uncommented some repos in the mirrorlist file?

Comment: No. nothing is commented or uncommented.

Comment: Can you please show us your mirrorlist?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I have to comment through an answer again, but I'm fairly certain the problem is as I mentioned.  I was able to replicate your behavior by not having any servers listed in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`.

First though, you said *"Nothing is commented or uncommented"*, which doesn't make any sense to me.  Your servers listed in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` must be either commented or uncommented.  You can find details [here in the Arch Linux Beginner's Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Select_a_mirror)

Assuming you have nothing at all listed in that file, you can use [Arch Linux's Pacman Mirrorlist Generator](https://www.archlinux.org/mirrorlist/), which entails the following:

1. Using the website to generate a `mirrorlist` file relevant to your country of residence
2. Uncomment any servers you want to use
3. Move the file to `/etc/pacman.d/`, and maybe `sudo chown root:root /etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist` so nothing weird happens with permissions

I do have one question though: *Why not just use Arch Linux?*

Comment: I have my exams coming up. My internet connection is through proxy which always makes it hard to connect to internet when it comes to arch. I tried arch linux before but always got stuck on the proxy part. Of course if I could get the pacman running in arch bang, I would surely move to arch linux. Could you tell me hw to configure the proxy settings in arch bang?

Comment: I did update the mirrorlist. It still doesn't work.

Comment: I know what you mean about the lack of time, but once you have a good amount of free time, it's worth the work, and helps you learn how to fix problems like this.
  Have you set the shell variable `http_proxy`?  Like this:
`su && export http_proxy=http://123.45.67.89:12345/ && pacman -Syy`.
  It looks like `wget` reads this variable, and you can use `wget` with `pacman`.

Comment: Yes i did set the shell variables as told in the wiki. Should the network connection be NAT or bridged?